# Using currentTime for gdrive video

Tags: javascript, html, video

On my website, I have a video from Google drive inside an HTML5 video tag. It's normal source url for `.mp4` file, so I didn't have all this control stuff like resolution settings etc. I used `currentTime` property in my script to return information in seconds about the current position of the video playback.

What I want to do, is to get this same information for this same video that includes all google options.

When I set video in `iframe` I have all options, but I can't invoke `js` in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't those "google options" the same as YouTube ones? Then it would be easier to host your videos on youtube, and use their [iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) to `getCurrentTime()`. Unfortunately, it's seems you still can't use the iframe API on google drive hosted videos... related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419914/does-the-youtube-player-api-apply-on-google-drive-embedded-videos

Comment: The videos i will work with are already uploaded on gdrive and they have more than hour long. Transfering them to Yt  would cost me an incredibly large amount of time.

Comment: Then either you do find the url of the different qualities versions, and you rebuild your own options, or you add a click listener on the iframe, checking if the mouse-position is around the play button, record a `var now = performance.now()` and getCurrentTime would be around `performance.now() - now`, but that's all hoping the user did click on the play button and not on the timeline, and that his connection allows him to play the video without any interruption. I'm afraid that the YT solution is still the easiest and more reliable way...